# How to mandate the derived class to instantiate the constructor of the base class

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I want to require a consumer of a class to pass a certain object to a class during initialization, to accomplish this I'd put it in the constructor.

For example:

```
public class Animal
{
   private string _name;
   public Animal(string name)
   {
     _name = name;
   }
}
```

I can't create `Animal` without passing a `Name`.

Ok now in my case I have a base class `Animal` and I defined a bunch of different derived classes from that class like `Human`, `Dog`, `Cat`, etc.

My question is, I want to make it impossible to instantiate any class deriving from `Human` without passing a `Name`. There are no abstract constructors in C# and I realize that I can create a constructor for each class to receive `Name` and just call the base constructor but the problem is I can also create a derived class type (Human, Dog, Cat, etc.) with a parameter-less constructor and instantiate it without passing a `Name` and I want to make sure anyone who creates a derived class must have a constructor receiving `Name`. I can also do some kind of run time checking and throw an error but I'd rather have a compile time error.

In short, how do I mandate the derived class to instantiate the constructor of the base class?

Comment: How can you instantiate `Animal` (or a derived class) *without* passing a name to `Animal`??

Comment: If you derive from a class that does not have a parameter-less constructor, you are forced to call that constructor from the deriving class. You can still have a parameter-less constructor in the derived class, but it will need to call the parameter-based constructor of the base class, i.e. `public Human() : base("Human") {}` .

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that derived class does not "see" empty ctor in base class. To make it available to children but not to direct consumers of the base class declare empty ctor as `protected`.

```
public class Animal
{
   private string _name;
   public Animal(string name)
   {
     _name = name;
   }

   /*visible to children only empty ctor*/
   protected Animal() {}
} 

public class Dog : Animal
{}

void Main()
{
    var d = new Dog();
}
```

User can not create `Animal` class without string argument, but can create derived class instance in that way.

Comment: If you add the constructor of the `Dog` class to your example it will explain the key challenge nicely.

Comment: I want to mandate the derived class to use a paramatered constructor so there should never be able to call var d = new Dog();

Comment: @Elitan: it's not what you asked in question. if so just simply remove protected ctor and keep the code you already have.